# Azure PostgreSQL flexible server is at 100% cpu utilization

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I have an Azure PostgreSQL (version 12) flexible server that has been running at 100% CPU utilization for the last 4 days and the server is currently using 70% of the storage. The Compute core is `Standard B1ms (1 vCPU and 2GB Memory)`

I have checked `SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');` and the response is 00:00:00

I have also checked the command `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` and the only applications runnings are `autovacuum launcher, pgms_stats_background_worker, pg_qs_background_worker, logical replication launcher, background writer, checkpointer and walwriter`

Since there is no query or active background process running, I am out of ideas on what the actual issue could be. Any assistance for this is appreciated.

Comment: Ask Microsoft, and good luck.

Comment: Perhaps your database has been hacked. Did you choose good passwords?

Comment: The database server is in the private zone so I don't think it's been compromised.

Comment: Can you provide an update? We consider using postgres flexible server as well since our use case of a tiny, low frequented web application is a good fit for the burstable instances. On the other hand we made the experience that features of azure doesn't behave as advertised. Your problem is something I had in mind when searching for orgs/people having experience with this particular service...